# Building up an Intuition for Using Inject in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand how and when to recognize that inject/reduce is more useful in Ruby code. So, for example, I know I can take this:

```
def add(numbers)
  sum = 0
  numbers.each { |n| sum += n }
  sum
end
```

That can be "reduced" to:

```
numbers.inject(0) { |sum, n| sum += n }
```

What I don't see, however, is how that works when you have a slightly more complicated expression. Here's what I'm wrestling with:

```
def process_data(condition, data)
  condition.each do |key, value|
    data = method("query_#{key}").call(data, value)
  end
  data
end
```

One of the problems is that I'm variable shadowing with `data` but I still struggle to find a way to treat this as something I'm injecting.

Is there a way people have found to turn this idiom into a heuristic that you can easily follow? It's these kinds of things that I feel I struggle with in Ruby, spending more time trying to be idiomatic Ruby.

So I guess perhaps my better question is this: is the `process_data` method that I show one that *should* be refactored to use reduce/inject to be idiomatic Ruby?

Comment: your first example can be simplified even more `numbers.reduce(:+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that ?

```
def process_data(condition, data)
  condition.reduce(data) { |data, (key,value)| method("query_#{key}").call(data, value) }
end
```

Comment: That definitely does the trick! I appreciate the concise example. Now I just have to get to the point where I can from code that I tend to create to the code you just showed me.

Comment: Well, if you have an array that you want to reduce to one result by applying a recurrent logic, then you can probably use reduce :)